# Does `git push` expand to `git push origin master`?

Tags: git, git-push

Or does it expand to `git push origin <current-branch-name>`?

#### References

- http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

  - `git push [remote-name] [branch-name]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

By default, `git push` expands to `git push origin <current-branch>` since `Git 2.0` or `git push origin <all-matching-branches>` for older versions.

#### The actual answer

The answers to all your questions regarding `git push` are in the documentation page of `git push`: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

A fragment from that page *(I removed the myriad of options as they are not mentioned in the question)*:

> `git push ... [<repository>] [<refspec>]`
>
> When the command line does not specify where to push with the `<repository>` argument, `branch.*.remote` configuration for the current branch is consulted to determine where to push. If the configuration is missing, it defaults to `origin`.
>
> When the command line does not specify what to push with `<refspec>...` arguments or `--all`, `--mirror`, `--tags` options, the command finds the default `<refspec>` by consulting `remote.*.push` configuration, and if it is not found, honors `push.default` configuration to decide what to push (See [`git-config[1]`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for the meaning of `push.default`).

Since `Git 2.0` the default value of `push.default` is `simple` which means **push current branch** with some checks and conditions that can make `git` refuse to `push` in some situations.

Before `Git 2.0`, the default value of `push.default` used to be `matching` which means **push all branches having the same name on both ends**. This mode also requires some conditions to be met in order to succeed.

For more details about `push.default` see the documentation page of [`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) or type `git help config` on your terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it expands to `git push origin master` if you are on master.

If you are on a branch `mybranch` it expands to `git push origin mybranch`.

If you have never pushed `mybranch`, this message will appear:

```
fatal: The current branch mybranch has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin mybranch
```

Then you have to execute `git push --set-upstream origin mybranch` once for the first `push`, and from then on you can just do a `git push` which will expand to `git push origin mybranch`.